# telnet connection failed on port 23

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, telnet

i'm suppose to log into remote machines using telnet but in the task i have, there's no ip adresses for that ! instead i have hostnames. i'm a bit new in this and i don't know what i'm suppose to get. i'm asked to try these following:

```
>telnet cs.purdue.edu
>telnet crete.dcs.gla.uk
```

i keep getting the same result:

```
Connecting To .......Could not open connection to the host, on 
port 23: Connect failed
```

i know the telnet command usually requires two arguments but it's not specified in this task! i tried to enable telnet on services but i didn't find it,  i also restarted the pc after downloading the telnet client and even tried to run the command several times and in two different computers but still the same result ! is there any solutions or clarification for this problem ?

OS : win 10

Comment: If you have specific instructions for whatever this assignment is, it would help if you could [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1374209/edit) your post and quote the instructions verbatim. It may become clearer to us what they're intending for you to do.

Comment: that's why i'm confused !! there's no much details ! at first they asked to try telnet with specifying the port then right away like this !! maybe the assignment is missing a part ! i'll check with the professor !! thank you

Comment: Is it possible that you should be in a certain specific network for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Port 23 is the usual telnet port.  You can't connect to cs.purdue.edu because they don't allow it.  I can't either.

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>telnet cs.purdue.edu
 Connecting To cs.purdue.edu...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

There's nothing you and I can do to make purdue accept telnet connections.

Have you been specifically directed to use telnet to cs.purdue.edu?

Comment: yes !! they're asking us to try those to see what we can possibly get !! but the result is always the same soo i thought maybe there's something wrong !! but apperently there's no solution for that !!! thank you 